# Problema com DatePicker JavaScript para datas maiores que 12

Tags: javascript

Estou a ter alguns problemas em selecionar datas superiores ao dia 12 de um determinado mês com o seguinte script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var date = new Date();
            var today = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate());
            $('#datepickerInicio').datepicker({
                defaultDate: today,
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                orientation: 'bottom',
                dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Segunda', 'Terça', 'Quarta', 'Quinta', 'Sexta', 'Sábado'],
                dayNamesMin: ['D', 'S', 'T', 'Q', 'Q', 'S', 'S', 'D'],
                dayNamesShort: ['Dom', 'Seg', 'Ter', 'Qua', 'Qui', 'Sex', 'Sáb', 'Dom'],
                monthNames: ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro'],
                monthNamesShort: ['Jan', 'Fev', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Set', 'Out', 'Nov', 'Dez'],
                nextText: 'Próximo',
                prevText: 'Anterior',
                locale: 'PT-pt',
                maxDate: today
            });

            $('#datepickerInicio').datepicker('setDate', today);

            console.log($('#datepickerInicio').data());
            console.log($('#datepickerInicio').val());
        });

        $('#btnSeach').click(function () {
            console.log($('#datepickerInicio').val());
        })
    </script>
```

Sendo que via consola:

defaultDate: Wed Jul 17 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0100

> datepicker: append: k.fn.init [] currentDay: 17 currentMonth: 6
> currentYear: 2019

Ou seja, supostamente a data deveria ser 17/07/2019. No entanto se eu colocar datas 12/07/2019 ou inferiores funciona perfeitamente.

Pelo que entendi tem a ver com o mês começar de 0 a 11, no entanto não faço ideia de como poderei resolver esta situação, pois o datetimepicker não aceita datas acima de dia 12 seja em que mês selecionado for.

Alguém sabe como poderei resolver este problema? É que supostamente o datetimepicker está a assumir o "dia" como "mês".

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, faz um teste antes de eu rodar seu código, exclui essa linha da declaração do dataPicker.

```
maxDate: today
```

Comment: Removendo essa linha tem exactamente o mesmo problema!